# Test Complete 12.0 connect to pid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testcomplete

I am writing a Test Complete test with C# which starts up a java program and interacts with it.  To start with, I would start the java process and connect to it.

```
 Connect.Sys["Process"]("java", 900000);
 rootNode = driver.WaitProcess("java");
```

to connect to my Java process I start up.  However, this works only when there is no java running (i.e., no java running until I start the process).  However, trying to get it to run on Jenkins which is also a java process so it tries to connect to the Jenkins java process instead of mine, and does not work.

I am using C# so I was able to get the PID of the Java Process (integer) to which I would like to connect.

But I am not sure how to do this.  I tried

```
 Connect.Sys["Pid"](javapid, 90000);
```

where javapid is the pid, but it gave me an unknown name error.
So does anyone have any suggestions how to connect to the pid?

And I can't use TestLeft.

```
 driver.waitProcess(processName)
```

just does a

```
 return Connect.Sys["WaitProcess"](processName, timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FindChild method instead:

```
 Connect.aqUtils["Delay"](10000);
 rootNode = Connect.Sys["FindChild"]("Id", javapid, 0);
```